# How do I embed an instagram feed into my cms website page?

Tags: iframe, instagram

How do I embed an instagram feed into my cms website, how to I create the iframe in instagram to put into my web page?

Comment: Thats not that easy. Look for the instagram api

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything about it on the api